# when does Go http.Get reuse the tcp connection?

Tags: sockets, http, go, tcp

in GO net/http Response Body annotation says:

> It is the caller's responsibility to close Body. The default HTTP client's Transport does not attempt to reuse HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 TCP connections ("keep-alive") unless the Body is read to completion and is
>   closed.

It's mean: if I use http.Get and don't call resp.Body.Close() then it will not resue HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 TCP connections ("keep-alive") yeah?

so I write some code:

```
package main
```

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8588")

```
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
_, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

resp2, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:8588")

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
_, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp2.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("before time sleep")
time.Sleep(time.Second * 35)
```

}
     
and I only see ONE tcp connection build in wireshark, why?
I don't close `res.Body` so the `http` client should't be reuse the tcp connection.

Comment: Perhaps the comment is wrong.  Once the response body is read to EOF, there's nothing preventing the client from reusing the connection.

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes, it's a error on comment. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22954
but the response body not read EOF. just read content-Length in http header then read Content-Length bytes from body.

Comment: "Read to EOF" shorthand for "read to the end of the response body".  Reading content-length bytes is reading to the end of the response body.

Answer (score 2):

this problem has been solved in
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22954.

Answer (score 0):

You have read it till the end in first occurence of line:

```
_, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

So the connection is ready to be resused. Try not to read and run again.

Comment: but in GO net/http comment, it says: 
"The default HTTP client's Transport does not attempt to reuse HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 TCP connections ("keep-alive") unless the Body is read to completion and is closed."
but i don't close the resp.Body.
so does we don't need close? just read completion is ready to be reuse?

Comment: the comment is not correct.